# Add more of my usercontrol container or usercontrol collection display

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, layout, user-controls

I do not know what the container/control im looking for would be called, so I cannot really search for it.

### Add More of Same Usercontrol Usercontrol

[image]

- Clicking on **`+`** would add a new instance of My Usercontrol to the right of the existing ones
- Clicking on **`X`** would dispose the usercontrol that was clicked
- I'm not really looking for a tab control that would put each new instance on a new tab, but if there is nothing else then it might do.
- The design is not to be as shown in the image obviously, the image just illustrates the basic idea

### *Any keyword/name suggestions or links to existing implementations?*

e.g. Maybe there is a style that turns a ListBox into something suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an `ItemsControl` and customize it's `ItemsPanelTemplate` to be whatever you want.

`ItemsControls` are meant for iterating through a collection of objects, and displaying them in whatever form you want. I wrote some simple code samples of them [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) if you're interested, or here's another quick example:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="RootPanel">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource AddButtonStyle}"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Command="{Binding AddItemCommand" />

    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <local:MyUserControl />

                        <Button Style="{StaticResource RemoveButtonStyle}"
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=RootPanel, Path=DataContext.RemoveItemCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Your ItemsControl would be bound to an `ObservableCollection` of objects, and your Add/Remove buttons would simply add/remove items from that collection. Since it is an `ObservableCollection`, it will notify the UI when the collection gets changed and automatically update.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use a ListBox and set its ItemTemplate and ItemsPanelTemplate:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Of course, your ItemTemplate would be a reference to your control.

Comment: thanks! i have a question remaining, the first comment to 53AN ?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at something called a carousel control which uses a list of objects behind it and displays them similarly to itunes. This could be a bit over the top but is one solution. An example can be seen [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFCarouselControl.aspx)

If this is too advanced for your needs, could it be as simple as a stackpanel with a scrollbar which is bound to a list of your user controls?

Comment: carousel looks sweet! in order to make it meet my needs though, 1) how could i make each item have an X clicking on which would remove that item, and 2) would i always add an item to the end of the list which would be the + usercontrol, clicking on which would add a new item?

Comment: In the template for each item you could add a button which when clicked would remove the selected item from the list which is bound to the carousel. This in turn would remove the item from the carousel. I haven't used the carousel control from the article linked. It was just the most complete example I found whilst looking. I would imagine adding an item to the list would add it to the end of the carousel list.